# Can I define a UIView both in a nib AND programmatically?

Tags: iphone, ios, view, nib

Is this common practice or frowned upon?  Are there any standards/resources for such a practice?  What are the alternatives?  I realize the question is broad, but I am new to iOS development and any information helps.  Thanks!

EDIT: I do mean the **same** view.

Comment: Do you mean, "can I define _the same_ view programmatically and in a nib?"  If so, I can't see a reason for doing that.  If you mean, can I define two views, one in IB and one in a nib, sure you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can interchange XIB-described objects with program-created ones, and you can do programed modifications of an XIB-instantiated object, or you can use an XIB-instantiated object inside a programmed view.

Basically an XIB just "generates code" (in a backwards sort of way) to instantiate the objects it describes, and once the root view and all of its subviews are created it's indistinguishable from its program-created twin.

Comment: Actually, a nib is an archive of objects which get de-archived upon load. No code is "generated" but objects are initialized from the archive.

Comment: WTP's comment is quite instructive as to the actual question, I think. A XIB is just an archived copy of the objects, in much the same way that any property list is. The various connections are achieved using ObjC's inherent reflection. So not only is no code generated per XIB, but it's fine to alter the objects once they've been loaded because, once created, they're not inherently different to objects created in any other way.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel, and WTP for the clarification.  So Daniel, if I were to do programmed modifications of a XIB-instantiated object, would I make those modifications in a view controller or a view of the same name?

Comment: Yeah, WTP, I was over-simplifying a bit.  The archived image does have to be interpreted somehow, so many of the motions of executing the code occur, but it's not literally generated code.

Comment: You can do modifications of the XIB-instantiated object from anywhere (within reason).  You just have to keep in mind that the "owning" view controller is the default responder/delegate.

Comment: This is also why viewDidLoad is provided on UIViewController — that's a hook to tell you that the XIB has just been loaded, so if you have any modifications to make then it's a good moment to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can mix use of programmatically created and nib loaded resources in any way you like - often the nib will be used to set up a skeleton that code might alter or add more views to.